# Отследить подключение и отключение питания

Tags: android

Пишу программу, отключающую смартфон при отключении питания, которая будет работать в фоне
Подскажите, как правильно отследить подключение / отключение кабеля питания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые события в Андроид ОС инициируются намерениями (`Intent`).
Соответственно смотрим документацию к этому классу и ищем подходящий action, для вашего случая их два:
[`android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
[`android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)
Видим в документации что это экшены широковещательной рассылки (`Broadcast`) - соответственно регистрируем ресивер

```java
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // your code when power connected
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // your code when power disconnected
        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
MyBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
```

---

```java
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
context.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```